# OpcUa Namespace change after restart of server

Tags: opc, opc-ua

I read nodeid value from opcua server. In first start of server NodeId is "ns=2;i=10934" and i read it well, but after server restart NodeId is change to "ns=4;i=10934". My app can't read value, because it remember NodeId "ns=2;i=10934". What procedure i can do, to resolve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good question - and often overlooked. I am assuming that you are developing your client application, so you are using some SDK for that.

As a main principle, in the client side, you should store your NodeIds with references to NamespaceUris instead of NamespaceIndexes. OPC UA has the type ExpandedNodeId, which can provide NamespaceUri instead of NamespaceIndex, and therefore it provides a better alternative for storing the IDs. Only, you will have to convert between NodeId and ExpandedNodeId to be able to store them and then do the same backwards to use the services, like read, in the server. Some SDKs make this easier than others, and you will need to consult the documentation of the one that you are using.

Another alternative is to save the NamespaceArray of the Server (available from the Server object) in your client and whenever you reuse NodeIds, you will compare the previous NamespaceArray with the current one, and then convert the NamespaceIndexes in all stored NodeIds respectively.